# SQL statement to update one table if value present in another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm fairly new to MSSQL and just have experience with some fairly basic update statements. I was wondering if someone might be able to help me with the correct syntax to do the following:

I have two tables, `F4101` and `F4102` that contain the same item IDs in the columns `IMITM (F4101)` and `IBITM (F4102)`.

Only F4102 needs to be updated, but it is updated based on F4101 and it needs to make sure that it is updating the correct item in F4102.

The statement needs to check where F4101 IMSRTX='RESIN' and then set F4102 IBBUYR=1009, while making sure that F4101 IMITM is equal to F4102 IBITM.

I appreciate the help!

Example Data:

```
F4101:
+-------+--------+
| IMITM | IMSRTX |
+-------+--------+
| 7493  | RESIN  |
| 7494  | MINOR  |
| 7495  | MINOR  |
| 7496  | RESIN  |
+-------+--------+

F4102:
+-------+--------+
| IBITM | IBBUYR |
+-------+--------+
| 7493  |        |
| 7494  |        |
| 7495  |        |
| 7496  |        |
+-------+--------+
```

if F4101 contains resin for an IMITM, it needs to update the IBBUYR column of F4102 with a value where the IMITM of F4101 is equal to the IBITM of F4102.

Comment: If you add example data and expected output it is easier to understand.

Comment: How many tables do you have in your database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE F4102 
SET    IBBUYR = 1009
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM F4101 
              WHERE IMITM  = F4102.IBITM 
              AND  IMSRTX = 'RESIN'
             )
```

Comment: Wouldn't this statement look for the IMSRTX column in the F4102 table? (IMSRTX is in F4101)

Comment: @dubfish well spotted :) I have fixed it

Comment: Something is off about the syntax with your statement when I put this in a query with the "And IMSRTX = 'RESIN'" portion.. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
Update F4102
Set IBBUYR=1009
From F4102 F2
Inner Join F4101 F1 on F2.IBITM = F1.IMITM
Where F1.IMSRTX='RESIN'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update tableA set tableA.col1='it works'
where tableA.Id=:aId 
and
(select true from customer where tableBId=:bId)
```

Something of this might work for you.